# Entity Framework wont add object to the database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

Out of curiosity, I started experimenting with Entity Framework and managed to get most of it working. Now here's the problem :

I'm using the code-first approach to save a simple object to a MySQL database. The code up to now is as follows.

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
      type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
    <providers>
      <provider 
        invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider 
        invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="LoginCon" 
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      connectionString="connectionString="server=localhost;
                                          port=3306;
                                          database=test;
                                          uid=root;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Model class**

```
public class LoginData {
        [Key]
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
}
```

**Database Context class**

```
public class LoginCon : DbContext {
    public DbSet<LoginData> Logins { get; set; }
}
```

When I perform things like

```
LoginData data = context.Logins.First(x => x.userId == 123);
```

or

```
context.Logins.Count();
```

I get the correct output. But when I do

```
LoginData log = new LoginData { userId= 321, password = "abc" };
context.Logins.Add(log);
```

I get an output

```
EntityType 'Login' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Logins: EntityType: EntitySet 'Logins' is based on type 'Login' that has no keys defined.
```

and the object is not added to the database at all. I've defined a primary key in the database

**Database structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
 `userId` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I know it's easier to generate the model from the database but I learned a lot doing all the things manually. So what am I doing wrong? Why wouldn't Entity Framework add the object to the database?

Comment: Please show your actual code, this does not contain a type `Login` as the error claims.

Comment: I slightly changed the variables etc. for better understanding. And I figured out the problem. I was not committing the changes. `context.SaveChanges()` fixed it.